# Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page showing when try to go wp-admin on my loacalhost. How to solve this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-admin

Last day everything was. But today when i am going to login to my dashboard. it's showing the above message.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to resolve your problem..

1. Make sure you clear any caching and deactivate any caching or performance plugins. This also includes server caching software like Varnish and hosted solutions such as CDNs such as Cloudflare. After any change you make in the steps below, clear your browser cache.
2. Start by taking a full backup of your WordPress site, including all files and the database.
3. Once you have a good backup, deactivate ALL plugins.
4. If the problem went away then you know it was caused by one of the plugins you deactivated. Reactivate each plugin one at a time until the problem occurs. You now know which plugin is causing your issue.
5. If the problem does not go away when you have deactivated plugins then switch to the default WordPress theme (currently this is Twenty Seventeen).
6. If the problem went away then you know it was caused by your theme.
   You can also enable ‘WP_Debug’ and check the debug log for error messages. For instructions on how to do this, please consult the WordPresss Codex.
7. If none of these resolve the issue, there may be a problem with the settings. Try resetting your settings to the defaults and see if that fixes the problem. But before you do this, you will want to export your settings so you can restore them after testing.